# flutter app freezes if animation is added inside futureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this application where I will have futurebuilder to get data first, and then return a scaffold with a separate splash screen to simulate the screen darken effect with alertdialog while enabling setstate (I tested, they dont allow setstate with alert dialog). However, when I used Animated Opacity, Color Tween or Animated Switcher, as soon as the screen loads, the app freezes.

code:

```
class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  GlobalKey imageKey = GlobalKey();
  late Animation splashAnimation;
  late AnimationController splashController;
  double splashOpacity = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    splashController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400));
    splashAnimation =
        ColorTween(begin: Colors.transparent, end: Color.fromARGB(155, 0, 0, 0))
            .animate(splashController);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    PageLoader pageLoader = context.watch<PageLoader>();
    TabProperty tabProperty = context.watch<TabProperty>();

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        //check if user logged in ? disable back btn : exit app
        bool login = false;
        await StorageManager.readData("loggedIn")
            .then((value) => login = value);
        if (login) {
          return false;
        } else {
          SystemNavigator.pop();
        }
        return false;
      },
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getMenuAndAccountInfo(pageLoader),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          //placeholder
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Stack(children: [
              SafeArea(
                child: Scaffold(
                  body: pageLoader.currentPage,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Color.fromARGB(100, 0, 0, 0),
              ),
              Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            ]);
          } else {
            List<dynamic> menuData =
                (snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>)["Menu"];

            return SafeArea(
              child: RepaintBoundary(
                key: imageKey,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Scaffold(
                      body: pageLoader.currentPage,
                      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
                        height: height * 0.07,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: MaterialButton(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  splashColor: Colors.orange,
                                  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {});
                                    splashOpacity = 1;
                                  },
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.bookmark,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        size: height * 0.035,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Bookmark",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: height * 0.02),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: MaterialButton(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  splashColor: Colors.orange,
                                  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {});
                                    splashOpacity = 1;
                                  },
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.account_circle_rounded,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        size: height * 0.035,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Profile",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: height * 0.02),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: AnimatedOpacity(
                        opacity: splashOpacity,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        child: Container(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(155, 0, 0, 0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER** build the future as the `future:` parameter to the FutureBuilder!

```
future: getMenuAndAccountInfo(pageLoader),
```

No!

Instead, you want to declare a variable to hold the future in State, and in initState, initialize that variable, and in your FutureBuilder, *reference* that variable.

For details, see the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see [my video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg) on that.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it but it doesnt answer the question I was hoping for.